Isomorphism between $\ell^p(\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}, \mathbb{R})$ and $\ell^p(\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{R})$
to apply the the Pełczynski decomposition technique I want to show that the infinte direct sum of $\ell^p$ is ismoetric isomorph to $\ell^p$. With infinte direct sum I mean:
$\ell^p(X) = \{(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty \in X^{\mathbb{N}} : \|x\|_p := \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \|x_n\|_X^p \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} < \infty\}$, called the infinite direct sum of $X$
The first idea I have read is that one can identify $\ell^p (\ell^p)$ (the infinite direct sum of $\ell^p$) as $\ell^p(\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N},\mathbb{R})$. So left to prove is that there is an isometric Isomorphismus between $\ell^p(\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}, \mathbb{R})$ and $\ell^p(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{R})$. Unfortunately I am stuck there.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
