$X \approx \ell^p(I,X)$ $\Rightarrow$ $X \approx X \oplus X$ (used in The Pełczynski decomposition technique)
In "A. Pełczynski, Projections in certain Banach spaces. Stud. Math. ´ 19, 209–228" the following relation is used as a fact (for The Pełczynski decomposition technique):
$X \approx \ell^p(I,X)$ (X isomorphic to the infinite direct sum of X)  $\Rightarrow$ $X \approx X \oplus X$ (X isomorphic to the direct sum of X and X).
My first problem is, how I have to understand $X \oplus X$. Is this different to the usual direct sum? For me $Y = Z \oplus W$ reads that every element in $Y$ has an unique representation $y = z + w$ with $z \in Z$ and $w \in W$. My idea is that the direct sum is build on two isomorphic copies of $X$ rather than $X$ itself. Nevertheless I didnt find any source that explains this further.
The second question is then how the stated relation can be proved. The proof of this relation is not explicitly provided in the article, suggesting it might be a straightforward argument.  However, it remains unclear to me.

What is $I$? Is it an infinite set?

@DeanMiller yes an infinte countable index set, thanks for clarification. In most cases it is that $I = \mathbb{N}$.

If $X$ is a vector space and if both $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ are vector subspaces over $X$ such that $X_{1} \cap X_{2} = \{0\}$, then it is possible to form another vector subspace which consists of all vectors of the form $x_{1} + x_{2}$ with $x_{1}\in X_{1}$ and $x_{2} \in X_{2}$. This is called the (algebraic) internal direct sum of $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ and is denoted by $X_{1} \oplus X_{2}$.
However, it is also possible to start with two vector spaces $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ over the same field $\mathbb{F}$ and attempt to define a vector space structure on $X_{1} \times X_{2}$. One way to do this is to perform operations component-wise, so that if $x_{1}, y_{1}\in X_{1}$, $x_{2}, y_{2}\in X_{2}$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}$, then $(x_{1}, x_{2}) + (y_{1}, y_{2}) := (x_{1} + y_{1}, x_{2} + y_{2})$ and $\alpha \cdot (x_{1}, x_{2}) := (\alpha x_{1}, \alpha x_{2})$. These operations define a vector space structure on $X_{1} \times X_{2}$. This is known as the (algebraic) external direct sum of $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ and is often also denoted by $X_{1} \oplus X_{2}$.
One reason why these concepts are closely related is that given a vector space $X$ and two vector subspaces $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ of $X$, there is a natural vector space isomorphism between the internal direct sum of $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$, and the external direct sum of $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$, where each vector in the internal direct sum of $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$, which is of the form $x_{1} + x_{2}$ for $x_{1}\in X_{1}$ and $x_{2} \in X_{2}$, is associated with the element $(x_{1}, x_{2})$ in the external direct sum of $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$. It can be verified that this correspondence is a vector space isomorphism between the internal direct sum of $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ and the external direct sum of $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$. Frequently both are referred to as the direct sum of $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ and in some cases they are even identified. It is the external direct sum that is being used here.
However, there is also the notion of a topological direct sum. Given two normed spaces $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ over the same field, there are many choices for a norm on the direct product $X_{1} \oplus X_{2}$. Given $p\in [1, \infty )$, one choice is
$$\|(x,y)\|_{\ell_{p}} := (\|x\|_{X_{1}}^{p} + \|y\|_{X_{2}}^{p})^{1/p}.$$
Another choice for $p = \infty$ is
$$\|(x,y)\|_{\ell_{p}} := \max \{\|x\|_{X_{1}}, \|y\|_{X_{2}}\}.$$
All of these norms are equivalent norms on $M\oplus N$, so it may be assumed that given $p\in [1, \infty ]$, $X_{1}\oplus X_{2}$ is equipped with the $\ell_{p}$-norm given above. This is known as a topological direct sum. Often a direct sum is taken as having the extra structure a topological direct sum provides.
It is also worth mentioning that two normed spaces $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic if there is a linear homeomorphism mapping $X$ onto $Y$. Such a map is called a normed space isomorphism, or isomorphism in this context.
To answer your second question, it is very long to type all of it up in detail, so I will sketch many details and will leave them to you to verify. I will be assuming that $X$ in the question is a Banach space. If $I$ is an infinite index set (not necessarily countable), it can be expressed as a disjoint union of two subsets $I_{1}$ and $I_{2}$ with the same cardinality as $I$. Fixing two such subsets, the idea is to show the following relations:
$$ X \cong \ell_{p}(I,X) \cong \ell_{p}(I_{1},X) \oplus \ell_{p}(I_{2},X) \cong \ell_{p}(I,X) \oplus \ell_{p}(I,X) \cong X \oplus X. $$
The relation $X \cong \ell_{p}(I,X)$ holds by assumption. Note that if $X_{1}$, $X_{2}$, $Y_{1}$ and $Y_{2}$ are normed spaces (over the same field) such that $X_{1}\cong Y_{1}$ and $X_{2}\cong Y_{2}$, then $X_{1}\oplus X_{2} \cong Y_{1} \oplus Y_{2}$. Indeed, if $g_{1} :X_{1}\to Y_{1}$ and $g_{2}:X_{2}\to Y_{2}$ are such isomorphisms, then the map $g:X_{1}\oplus X_{2} \to Y_{1}\oplus Y_{2}$ defined by $g(x,y) := (g_{1}(x), g_{2}(y))$ can be verified to be an isomorphism. As $X\cong \ell_{p}(I,X)$, it follows from above that $\ell_{p}(I,X)\oplus \ell_{p}(I,X) \cong X\oplus X$.
Whenever $J$ is a set which has the same cardinality as $I$, there is a bijective map $\varphi:I\to J$. Then the map $\psi :\ell_{p}(J,X)\to \ell_{p}(I,X)$ defined by $\psi (f) := f\circ \varphi$ can be verified to be an isometric isomorphism. Consequently, $\ell_{p}(J,X) \cong \ell_{p}(I,X)$ whenever $J$ has the same cardinality as $I$. Applying this result to $I_{1}$ and $I_{2}$, it follows that $\ell_{p}(I_{1},X) \cong \ell_{p}(I,X)$ and $\ell_{p}(I_{2},X) \cong \ell_{p}(I,X)$. As a consequence, $\ell_{p}(I_{1},X) \oplus \ell_{p}(I_{2},X) \cong \ell_{p}(I,X) \oplus \ell_{p}(I,X)$.
All that is left is to establish $\ell_{p}(I,X) \cong \ell_{p}(I_{1},X) \oplus \ell_{p}(I_{2},X)$. Assuming that $\ell_{p}(I_{1},X) \oplus \ell_{p}(I_{2},X)$ is equipped with the $\ell_{p}$-norm, it can be verified that the map $\phi :\ell_{p}(I,X) \to \ell_{p}(I_{1},X) \oplus \ell_{p}(I_{2},X)$ defined by $\phi (f) := (f\vert_{I_{1}}, f\vert_{I_{2}})$ is an isometric isomorphism. As a composition of isomorphisms is an isomorphism, it follows that $X \cong X\oplus X$.

$\textbf{Step 1:}$ $X_1 \cong Y_1 \quad \text{and} \quad X_2 \cong Y_2 \Rightarrow X_1 \oplus X_2 \cong Y_1 \oplus Y_2$

Bijective: $g_{1}, g_{2}$ are bijective.
Isometry: Using that $g_{1}, g_{2}$ are Isometries it follows that  $\Vert g(x,y) \Vert_{\ell^p} = \Vert (g_{1}(x), g_{2}(y)) \Vert_{\ell^p} = \left( \Vert g_{1}(x) \Vert_{X_{2}}^{p} + \Vert g_{2}(y) \Vert_{Y_{2}}^{p} \right)^{1/p} \
= \left( \Vert x \Vert_{X_{1}}^{p} + \Vert y \Vert_{Y_{1}}^{p} \right)^{1/p} = \Vert (x,y) \Vert_{\ell^p}$


$\textbf{Step 2:}$ is shown here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4909653/1318343 where I assumed that I is countable.

$\textbf{Step 3:}$ $\phi: \ell^p(I,X) \rightarrow \ell^p(I_1,X) \oplus \ell^p(I_2,X) \quad \text{defined by} \quad \phi(f) := (f|{I_1}, f|{I_2})$ is a isometric isomorphism


Bijective: Injective since $I_{1}$ and $I_{2}$ are disjoint and surjective since $I_{1} \cup I_{2}= I$
Isometry: $\Vert \phi(f) \Vert_{\ell^p} = \Vert (f|{I_1}, f|{I_2}) \Vert_{\ell^p} = \left( \Vert f|{I_1} \Vert_X^{p} + \Vert f|{I_2} \Vert_X^{p} \right)^{1/p} \
= \left( \left( \sum_{i \in I_1} \vert f(i) \vert^{p} \right) + \left( \sum_{i \in I_2} \vert f(i) \vert^{p} \right) \right)^{1/p} \
= \left( \sum_{i \in I} \vert f(i) \vert^{p} \right)^{1/p} = \Vert f \Vert$


Thanks for your detailed answer! I genuinely appreciate it. I tried to prove the left gaps. Could you be so kind to review it? @DeanMiller

No problem! What you did for step 1 is fine if $X_{1}$ is isometrically isomorphic to $Y_{1}$ and if $X_{2}$ is isometrically isomorphic to $Y_{2}$, but that is not assumed in this case. Instead, you want to show that $g$ and $g^{-1}$ are both continuous using that $g_{1}$ and $g_{2}$ are linear homeomorphisms. For step 3, the isometry portion of the argument looks good, but $\phi$ is injective because $I_{1}$ and $I_{2}$ cover $I$ and is surjective because $I_{1}$ and $I_{2}$ are disjoint, so you had those conditions the wrong way around. Everything else looks good.

It is also worth briefly mentioning that you used $| f\vert_{I_{1}} |^{p}{X}$ and $| f\vert{I_{2}} |^{p}{X}$ rather than $| f\vert{I_{1}} |^{p}{\ell^{p}(I,X)}$ and $| f\vert{I_{2}} |^{p}_{\ell^{p}(I,X)}$ while showing that $\phi$ is an isometry in step 3. But I assume that is just a typo.

yes you are right. For the missing proof why $g$ and $g^{-1}$ are continuous: $g$ continuous as component wise continuity of $g_{1}$ and $g_{2}$. For the inverse I would just argue with the Open Mapping Theorem since $g$ is a linear bounded operator and bijective. is that right? @DeanMiller

That is right as to why $g$ is continuous. Applying the open mapping theorem or bounded inverse theorem to conclude that $g^{-1}$ is continuous is valid if all of the normed spaces in question are Banach spaces, but you can also do it without using those results by noting that $g^{-1}(x,y) = (g_{1}^{-1}(x), g_{2}^{-1}(y))$ for all $x\in Y_{1}$ and $y\in Y_{2}$ combined with an analogous argument as to the continuity of $g$. This way, the result is also valid in the normed space case as well and the proof uses results which are more elementary than the open mapping theorem.

that makes sense! thank you

you mentioned above that the internal and external direct sum are isomorph. I tried to prove this with $f(x,y) = x+y$ as the isomorphism. Linearity is clear. Surjective and Injective follows from the unique representation of every element in the internal direct sum. Nevertheless I am not sure about the continuity of both f and the inverse. Which norms do we use to prove this. Is it the mentioned "topological direct sum norm"? I hope my question is clear otherwise just ask! @DeanMiller

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
